# What's the rule of "__block Variables" memory management?

Tags: ios, variables, object, memory-management, block

I read the "Blocks Programming Topics" ducument. But I'm not very clear about the `__block Variables`'s management.

When the `__block Variables` is a type of standard C scalar(like int, double), everything is Ok. But if it is a object. When I copy the related block variable using `Block_copy()`. I found the object's retainCount is always 1. So how can I manage the memory? Whether I only need to do is manage the related block variable use `Block_release`, and the runtime system will take care of the `__block Variables`.

I'm not a native Engnish speaker, I hope you can understand me.

Comment: if you have ARC on, it will manage the memory for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In non-ARC case __block modifier don't increase retainCount. You have to manually manage the lifetime of the object

Comment: I kown, but I'm confused about how to manage it manually. Just like the other object, if I own it then I release it? If no one own it, it will be released

Comment: It seems the __block Variables always be the same address in the memory. And it was share by all the copy of the related block var(use Block_copy()).